# azure hybrid connection to windows server with AD (ldap)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, azure-web-app-service

We have got Windows Server with AD on premis, and we would like to have access to this AD (by ldap) from App Service hosted in Azure.

It is possible by using Hybrid Connection?
I've read somewhere that Hybrid Connections are based only on TCP, and the LDAP uses UDP (sometimes?).
The App service has code that connect on LDAP and query AD by LDAP.
It is possible there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

[Hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) isn't used in this manner. It utilizes an agent that's installed on an on-prem server that establishes a relay connection. This connection allows the app service to connect to your SQL server as if it were hosted in the cloud.

I think what you may want to look at is something like [AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-whatis) which allows you to do [hybrid identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity) and sync your on-prem AD with Azure AD. You can learn more about AD Connect architecture [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/concept-azure-ad-connect-sync-architecture) but I don't know if what sort of protocol/connection it uses to do the sync. That may be dependent on the [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/choose-ad-authn) of sync you choose.

After you've synced, the users should be in your AAD tenant in which you can leverage the Microsoft Graph API to read group permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Things you cannot do with Hybrid Connections

Mount a drive.
Use UDP.
Access TCP-based services that use dynamic ports, such as FTP Passive Mode or Extended Passive Mode.
Support LDAP, because it can require UDP.
Support Active Directory, because you cannot domain join an App Service worker

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections